# How to get information about the sequence behind the new Identity Column in Postgres 10? (GENERATED { ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT } AS IDENTITY)

Tags: postgresql, identity, postgresql-10

Postgres 10 brings an implementation of the SQL standard [`GENERATED { ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT } AS IDENTITY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createtable.html) feature, loosely known as [*identity column*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_column). This feature supplants Postgres’ own [`SERIAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) pseudo-type, eliminating its issues/problems. For more info, see [here](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-10-identity-columns/) and [here](https://www.depesz.com/2017/04/10/waiting-for-postgresql-10-identity-columns/).

One of the main reasons for `GENERATED…` being superior to `SERIAL` is that the sequence number generator is handled in the background transparently. We can add the column, adjust the current sequence number, and drop the column, all without referring explicitly to the sequence.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    col  BIGINT 
         GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY 
         PRIMARY KEY ,
    col2 text
) 
;
```

And…

```
ALTER TABLE tbl
ALTER COLUMN col
RESTART WITH 1000
;
```

And…

```
ALTER TABLE tbl
ALTER COLUMN col
DROP IDENTITY IF EXISTS
;
```

Or…

```
ALTER TABLE tbl
ALTER COLUMN col
DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS
;
```

Note how in none of that example code did we refer to a specific sequence-generating object.

I presume this feature is implemented using the existing [Sequence feature](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createsequence.html) in Postgres.

➠ How do we query this background sequence? How do we ask what the last/next value generated will be? What is the equivalent of the [Sequence manipulation functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears you use the same functions as before:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-info.html

> pg_get_serial_sequence returns the name of the sequence associated
>   with a column, or NULL if no sequence is associated with the column.
>   ***If the column is an identity column, the associated sequence is the
>   sequence internally created for the identity column***. For columns
>   created using one of the serial types (serial, smallserial,
>   bigserial), it is the sequence created for that serial column
>   definition. In the latter case, this association can be modified or
>   removed with ALTER SEQUENCE OWNED BY. (The function probably should
>   have been called pg_get_owned_sequence; its current name reflects the
>   fact that it has typically been used with serial or bigserial
>   columns.) The first input parameter is a table name with optional
>   schema, and the second parameter is a column name. Because the first
>   parameter is potentially a schema and table, it is not treated as a
>   double-quoted identifier, meaning it is lower cased by default, while
>   the second parameter, being just a column name, is treated as
>   double-quoted and has its case preserved. The function returns a value
>   suitably formatted for passing to sequence functions (see Section
>   9.16). **A typical use is in reading the current value of a sequence for an identity or serial column, for example**:
>
> SELECT currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('sometable', 'id'));

Comment: I think it’s an oversight that the documentation neglects to mention this when discussing IDENTITY columns.